# OBSOLETE - Live Home Page - Never touch the refresh button on the home page of a Stack Exchange site again!

Tags: script, obsolete, live

> ### Feature implemented and this script retired
>
> This script is no longer needed since this feature is now built-in. This post will remain here for historical purposes.

### About

Live Home Page is a simple UserScript that updates the home page of any Stack Exchange site with questions as they are asked. Any activity on a question will bump it to the top of the home page and some nice jQuery animations will proudly announce its arrival! This script is very easy to use: just install it and visit the home page of a Stack Exchange site.

#### License

[The MIT license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)

#### Download

You can download the script here:
<s>http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/live_home.user.js</s>

#### Platform

Live Home Page runs on any browser that supports UserScripts. That includes Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera. Internet Explorer users need to find a new browser (just kidding, but there is currently no method of running a UserScript in IE that I know of).

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

Written in JavaScript using jQuery.

Comment: It's awesome how you give your personal email for contact & support. Have you considered open sourcing the script on github and using the github issue tracker for that kind of service.

Comment: @Raynos: It is open-source, but at such a small size I don't know if it's worth opening up a GitHub account and registering it there (I usually use Launchpad for code hosting). Feel free to post an answer or comment if you have any questions, suggestions, or bug reports.

Comment: github was just an example, I was an off-hand recomendation that some kind of web based system like launchpad / github / google code might be more suitable then personal email.

Comment: Useful script, thanks! Two suggestions I would like: 1) some sort of visual indication (perhaps temporary) of questions that have just been loaded. When more than as screen-full of new questions loads, it can take a moment to find your place. 2) abbreviation to kviews. View counts over 1000 are slightly overflowing their column.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Thanks! I'll see if those two issues can be fixed.

Comment: Please update this so tag pages get updated too. :) e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23

Comment: Aww, no question highlighting for favorite tags. :(